# How can I make someone else an Admin on my Company's Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook

We currently have over 1,000 "fans" on Facebook.  I'd like to make someone else an admin, but I don't want to have to go through all 1,000+ people to find the person I want to make an admin.

Is there an easy way to make someone an admin of your page without going through that list?  I was hoping that the "x Friends like this" list would have the "Make Admin" button like the list of people that like your page does, but alas, it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a specific person you want to make an admin?

Comment: Matthew, yes, someone that is a friend on FB already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are friends with the person you want to make admin, go to your companies page and click the 'Edit Page' button under your page's profile picture. On that page in the right column near the bottom it will list 'Admins' with an 'Add' link. This will give you your personal friends list which you can search on and select people to become admins.

Comment: Awesome Joel.  Thanks!  Hey Facebook, if you're listening, add the "Add Admin" button to my Friends list on the company page just like you have it for the list of fans.  Thanks again Joel!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make admin to anyone of your Facebook fan page. You can see an option on the right hand side of your Facebook fan page while login to Facebook.

Or you can read proper guide from here: http://www.bloggingalerts.com/2011/11/how-to-make-someone-admin-to-your.html

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

We have to go through this all the time and the best solution we've come up with so far is "get the person to remove themselves as a fan, then add themselves back". At least then, they're at the top of that huge list when you go to make them an admin. Yes, it's a pain, but that's facebook for you ...